# How does Playwright tracing file compare to HAR file?

Tags: playwright, har

Playwright lets you record HAR, but there's also `context.tracing.start`. The latter also lets you capture screenshots to the resulting ZIP, but HAR file seems to be better supported outside of Playwright. So what is the difference, are trace files basically HAR files with screenshots, or is there any info missing that would be found in a HAR?

Answer (score 0):

Playwright Tracing enables you to see screenshots, DOM Snapshots, console logs, Playwright method calls etc. These can be viewed using the Playwright trace viewer.

HAR is a file specification which supports only network requests, these can be viewed e.g. in Chrome DevTools.

See here for more information about the trace viewer: https://playwright.dev/docs/next/trace-viewer

Comment: My problem with PW tracing is that you can only see it in their viewer, and I could not find a way to change it to view the full url (domain + path), with HAR looks like there are more and better tools

Comment: Also, I just did a test run with both trace and HAR. Har is 2.3M, trace (after unzipping) is 1.3M, shouldn't trace be larger?